# Compare integers

Tags: php, integer, compare

```
$a = somenumber;
$b = somenumber;
```

**How do I know which variable has the biggest number?** What is the shorter way for this task.

Each number is a positive integer without residue.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't tried anything yourself? Your previous question was reasonable, but this one involves basic arithmetic...

Comment: max($a, $b) is what I searched for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`max`](http://php.net/max) returns the largest value from a list of values:

```
$biggest = max($a, $b);
```

If you care about which variable contains a higher value, use `>`, as other answers have said.

Comment: How would one know which is bigger then until you compare `$biggest` to either one? And if you had to do that, you might as well use `>` instead.

Comment: @BoltClock It depends what you want to do. If the value is the only thing that matters, `max` is the way to go. I've updated my answer to attempt to alleviate your concern

Comment: Yeah it turns out that was what OP wanted. The question as it was implied that we had to find out which *variable* held the bigger value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator:

```
$big = ($a > $b) ? $a : $b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Kidding?

```
if ($a > $b) {
    // $a is bigger
} else {
    // $b is bigger
}
```

or

```
$bigger = max($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function is_a_bigger($a, $b) {
    return ($a - $b > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($a > $b) {
 echo '$a is bigger';
} else 
 echo '$b is bigger';
}
```